# Breaking on `die` in Perl debugger

Tags: perl, debugging

Does the Perl debugger support breaking on `die`?

I find myself often running a program once to find the `die` line, then running it a second time to set a breakpoint.

It'd be nice if the debugger could be made to automatically break on `die`, holding on to the dying context.

Comment: ...or more generically on any exit. `Carp`, `exit`, `die`, uncaught exception, etc..

Answer (score 3):

You could set a `__DIE__` handler and set a breakpoint in it.

```
$SIG{__DIE__} = sub {
    $DB::single = 1;
    die @_;
};
```

This isn't a great answer, as inside the `__DIE__` handler you don't have the context of the function that called `die`. But the global package variables will be accessible, and if you have [`PadWalker`](https://metacpan.org/pod/PadWalker) installed then with the debugger command `y 1` or `y 1 <pattern>`, you can view the lexical variables in scope when `die` was called.

Proof-of-concept:

```
# dying.pl
$SIG{__DIE__} = sub { $DB::single = 1; die @_; };

for my $i (1 .. 10000) {
    my $j = sqrt($i * ($i+1)) - 0.49;
    die "$i $j" if $j - int($j) < 0.1;
}

$ perl -d dying.pl

Loading DB routines from perl5db.pl version 1.37
Editor support available.

Enter h or 'h h' for help, or 'man perldebug' for more help.

main::(dying.pl:1):     $SIG{__DIE__} = sub { $DB::single = 1; die @_; };
  DB<1> c
main::CODE(0x1000c918)(dying.pl:1):
1:      $SIG{__DIE__} = sub { $DB::single = 1; die @_; };
  DB<1> y 1 j
$j = 13.000737563232
  DB<2> y 1
$i = 13
$j = 13.000737563232
  DB<3> c
13 13.000737563232 at dying.pl line 5.
Debugged program terminated.  Use q to quit or R to restart,
  use o inhibit_exit to avoid stopping after program termination,
  h q, h R or h o to get additional info.  
  DB<3>
```